# Pandas Memory Error when read.csv ("Error tokenzing data..."

Tags: python, memory, pandas

I have a csv file that is about 500MB. I am trying to read it in.

```
 df = pd.read_csv(My_CSV_File.csv, low_memory=False)
```

I get this error:

```
 CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory
```

I don't think this csv file is considered anything close to large for pandas's read_csv to handle. I've tried some other options in read_csv such as setting but none worked. What can I do in this case?

Comment: Usual questions, are you using and running python 64-bit? Also I believe l`low_memory` is ignored

Comment: It's 32-bit. If I have to use 32-bit, is there any way to resolve the memory issue? Thanks.

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do here? Do you need to read the whole thing into memory? For instance you can pass a `chunksize` operate on the chunk and write to csv and on each iteration append to the csv

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will give chunksize a try.

Comment: One of the things low memory ignores is mixed datatypes. Have you tried specifying column dtypes?